# profile loss statement report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i want to  make crystal report of profit and loss statement
i have a  column of "vr_type" and there are 4 types in it "sale invoice", purchase invoice" now i want that put a 4  formula s where i select that "sum (vr_detail.debit) where vr_detail.vr_type} sale invoice it make Sum of al these types so kindly tell me what formula i should use to get the result 
in simply i want sum of sale,sum of purchase,sum of expense
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports doesn't have a sumif() function.  You will need to create a formula field for each type of field that you want to summarize, then insert a Summarized field on the formula field.

For example, you could create a field named 'sales invoice'.  The text of the formula would be:

```
if {vr_detail.vr_type}="sales invoice" then
  {vr_detail.debit}
else
  0
```

You would then select this field, then Insert | Summary...

You'll need to repeat this for each field.

** edit **
If you simply want subtotals by vr_type, follow these steps:

1. Insert a group on the {vr_detail.vr_type} field.  This will add a group-header (GH) and group-footer (GF) section to the report.
2. Insert a summarized field on the {vr_detail.debit} and/or {vr_detail.credit} field.

Comment: i know these query but problem is i have four types 'sale','purchase'payment','expense'and i want that this formula show four time according to their types

Comment: So, you want to group the report by the {vr_detail.vr_type} column, but total by the {vr_detail.debit} column?  Perhaps you could edit your question and add a sample of how you want the report to look.